# How to stop SQL from trying to convert nvarchar to INT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run a simple query in SQL, but I keep getting the error"

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'EA000006' to data type int.

I don't want SQL to convert the data to INT, I want it to simply show all the results in the column as they are normally stored. What is causing my script to try and convert this field? The script is a simple:

```
SELECT
    A.OrderNbr as 'Order Number' (The Field Causing the error)
   ,A.OrderDate as 'Order Date'
   ,B.InventoryCD as 'SKU'
   ,A.TranDesc as 'Descrption'
   ,A.OrderQty as 'Quantity'
   ,A.ExtPrice as 'Price'
   ,C.Distributor_ID as 'Distributor ID'
   ,C.First_Name as 'First Name'
   ,C.Last_Name as 'Last Name'
   ,C.Ship_Address as 'Ship Address'
   ,C.Ship_Address_2 as 'Ship Address 2'
   ,C.Ship_City as 'Ship City'
   ,C.Ship_Region as 'Ship State'
   ,C.Ship_Country as 'Ship Country'
   ,C.Ship_Postal_Code as 'Ship Postal Code'
   

  FROM [SOLine] A
    LEFT JOIN [InventoryItem] B
      ON A.InventoryID = B.InventoryID AND A.CompanyID = B.CompanyID
    LEFT JOIN [Orders] C
      ON A.OrderNbr = C.Order_ID

  WHERE  A.OrderDate >= '2020-01-01'
    AND A.OrderDate < '2021-01-01'
```

Comment: The values on both sides of the equal sign should have the same type. You may be comparing an nvarchar to an int.

Comment: Provide a [example].

Comment: The condition is really the whole equality. So is the left side an expression? Are you using quotes properly?

Comment: I have updated the script field with a more descriptive version of the script. My where clause isn't looking in the field that is casing the error.

Comment: Look at `ON A.OrderNbr = C.Order_ID`. What are the datatypes of those 2 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this join clause is evaluated:

```
ON A.OrderNbr = C.Order_ID
```

values of different types (`nvarchar` versus `int`) must be converted to the same type for the comparison according to [data type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql). One way to avoid the error is to explicitly convert the `int` column to `nvarchar`. For example (assuming `Order_ID` is int):

```
ON A.OrderNbr = CAST(C.Order_ID AS nchar(10))
```

Before doing so, be aware of some implications:

- the conversion will prevent an index on `Order_ID` from being used efficiently
- the comparison will follow character instead of numeric comparison rules (e.g. `OrderNbr` value "00" will not equal `Order_ID` value 0)
- the error may be because you are comparing the wrong columns since the types should be the same if they are are actually the same attribute